# sql slow postgresql dbeaver

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using DBeaver to query a PostgreSQL database.
I have this query, it simply selects the highest id per Enterprise_Nbr.  The query works but is really slow.  Is there any way I can rewrite the query to improve performance.

I am using the querytool DBeaver because I don't have direct access to PostgreSQL.  The ultimate goal is to link the PostgreSQL with PowerBi.

```
select * 
from public.address 
where "ID"  in (select max("ID") 
  from public.address a 
  group by "Enterprise_Nbr")
```

Comment: Please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: I think your query is wrong if `"ID"` isn't unique. Using `where ("Enterprise_Nbr", "ID") in (select "Enterprise_Nbr", max("ID") from ...)` is probably more robust

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: your query goes faster.  Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries for [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problems are typically faster if done using Postgres' proprietary `distinct on ()` operator

```
select distinct on ("Enterprise_Nbr") *
from public.address
order by "Enterprise_Nbr", "ID" desc;
```